# How to retrieve data from Azure Blob storage

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

Tell me the code to read the csv data in Blob storage in the python programming model v2 of Durable functions.

By the way, I am currently writing this in my activity function.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("origin_analysis", '')
    return "finished"

@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob", path="dataset/housing.csv", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def origin_analysis(blank: str):
    # Read dataset
    housing = pd.read_csv("housing.csv")
    housing.sample(5)
```

The above code does not seem to read in Azure functions, so please tell me how to read the data in the specified container of Blob storage.

As I recall, I could output data without importing 'BlobstrageClient' etc., so I don't want to add more libraries to import.

Comment: Should the `origin_analysis` function include the name of the bound arg? `def origin_analysis(blank: str, inputblob: func.InputStream):`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to read the csv data from Blob storage.

**Code**-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import pandas as pd

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

### client function ###
@app.route(route = "orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name = "client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, { })
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
    return f"Output: {status.output}"

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name = "context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result = yield  context.call_activity("origin_analysis", "")
    return result

@app.blob_input(arg_name = "inputblob", path = "dataset/Test.csv", connection = "BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name = "blank")
def origin_analysis(blank: str, inputblob: func.InputStream):
    # Read dataset
    housing = pd.read_csv(inputblob)
    data = housing.sample(n = 3, replace = True)
    res = data.to_dict()
    return res
```

You can change the value of **'n'** in `housing.sample()` as per your data volume in csv.

*I have below data in the blob storage-*

[image]

*I am able to get the expected output as shown below-*

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (there are *many* reasons- look at the meta post)

Comment: I have presented the code in text format and shared the output as an image due to the impracticality of pasting it as text.

Comment: The output can be copy/pasted. Easily. And it's far less impractical to do so than the effort someone would need to go through to convert your image to text (or to even *read* it, in some cases)